# Is putting "for a moment" between subject and verb grammatical?

Tags: adverbials

I'm not a native speaker of English. When I was reading *The Da Vinci Code*, I encountered the following sentence.

> He for a moment looked as if he'd seen a ghost.

I heard that a sentence can be unnatural and grammatical at the same time in linguistics. Is the sentence in this case, or the sentence is ungrammatical but allowed in literature?

Comment: I'd say it's towards the 'reject' end of the acceptability scale. Most adverbs have a very free distribution, but not a totally free one. Longer adverbials are, I'd say, less freely distributed. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+looked+for+a+moment%2CHe+for+a+moment+looked&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20looked%20for%20a%20moment%3B%2Cc0), and raw Google search results, would seem to indicate preferred usage.

Comment: More idiomatic to say *For a moment, he looked as if he'd seen a ghost* and keep both parts of the verb together. If in doubt,my own rule is to keep the verb parts (person and verb itself) together.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it.  There are other orderings that are more idiomatic, but changing the order may serve the author's needs in terms of pace or "mood".

Answer (score 1):

***The Da Vinci Code*** isn't ***the*** most poorly written work of fiction I've ever read, but so very close. However, who am I to argue with success? From Dan Brown's own website: http://www.danbrown.com/#author-section

As **Edwin Ashworth** and **WS2** stated:

"I'd say it's towards the 'reject' end of the acceptability scale. Most adverbs have a very free distribution, but not a totally free one. Longer adverbials are, I'd say, less freely distributed. These Google Ngrams, and raw Google search results, would seem to indicate preferred usage."

and,

"[It's] more idiomatic to say For a moment, he looked as if he'd seen a ghost and keep both parts of the verb together. If in doubt,my own rule is to keep the verb parts (person and verb itself) together."